# Versioning my project C# .NET 7 : year.month.buildNumber

Tags: c#, versioning, .net-7.0

I want to automatically create the version of my project every time I build it and create my own template : year.month.build.
I am using C# .NET 7.

In the csproj file I am able to choose the version :
At the moment I can do that and it is working :

```
<GenerateAssemblyInfo>true</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
<AssemblyVersion>$([System.DateTime]::UtcNow.ToString(`yyyy.MM.0.0`))</AssemblyVersion>
```

I saw that I can access the build and revision number using *. So I would like something like that :

```
<GenerateAssemblyInfo>true</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
<AssemblyVersion>$([System.DateTime]::UtcNow.ToString(`yyyy.MM.*`))</AssemblyVersion>
```

I want * to be the build version. But when I do that, I get 2023.4.0.0. I get 0 for the build version.

Then I tried to do that in my main.cs :

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("2023.4.*")]
```

In the csproj, I have to specify that I don't want the AssemblyInfo to be generated.
This way I get the right build.revision numbers but I have to specify the year and month in the code.

What I want is a combination of both. I want the date and build version to be set automatically. If possible, I don't want the revision number at the end.

Comment: What is "buildNumber"? By default build tools do not track this info (for obvious reasons).

Comment: Also maybe you will be interested in [`Nerdbank.GitVersioning`](https://github.com/dotnet/Nerdbank.GitVersioning) library.